# Do Tesla deal double damage to PEKKA?

Tags: clash-royale

It always feels like my PEKKA get melted by Tesla.

In Clash of Clans, Hidden Tesla deal 2x damage to PEKKA. Is this also the case in Clash Royale? Do PEKKA and Mini PEKKA receive double damage from Tesla?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, the Tesla does not deal double damage to the P.E.K.K.A**
The answer to this can easily be found on the [Clash Royale Wikia](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Tesla).

> Unlike in Clash Of Clans, the Tesla does not deal double damage to P.E.K.K.A.

Comment: And how do they know that?

Comment: Because they tested it and at the tesla description there is no statement says that it deals 2x damage to PEEKA.

Comment: Update: In Clash of Clans, the ×2 Damage modifier from the Tesla against P.E.K.K.A. has been removed.

Answer (score 4):

**No, the Tesla damages the P.E.K.K.A as much as it would do to any other target.** In fact, *there are no damage modifiers in Clash Royale*, excepting the damage caused by spells to Crown Towers.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't deal double damage and this is at first weird for the CoC players, but it is a good design decision.

For 4 mana Tesla allows you to have a tower that is not damageable by spells and when it pops up, it confuses the troops for half a second, giving the defender more time free of damage.

If it did deal double damage it would be highly overpowered.